# jQuery load() path of CakePHP elements()

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I try to load elements from CakePHP (`$this->elements()`) with the jQuery function `.load()` but I have prolems figuring out the paths to those elements. I found some other topics here on this site, but they didnt help me really.

The root is */webroot* isn't it? I tried then `.load('../View/Elements/Summoners/comments.ctp');` and some other paths but they didn't work out :/

Comment: You can't mix jQuery and PHP code. You'll need to make an action/view that is called using the jQuery `.load()` function which in turns renders your element.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use jQuery to load the elements? Why is simply putting `$this->Element('elementName');` in your view not an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load the element from jQuery, but call a controller method that will load the element. For example. In jQuery call something like:

```
.load(/controller/ajax_action/);
```

Then in the controller that corresponds to ajax_action, you can either let it load the view it is calling or load the element like so:

```
public function ajax_action() {
    $this->renderElement('/elements/element_name.ctp');
}
```

Comment: Just a clarification note: The jQuery "path" specified is a URL *not* a file system path. Which is where it seems the OP got confused.

Comment: @Chad: I think the OP thought "since I already have the element why not load it directly" without realizing what you mention here. I guess for all intents and purposes, the OP could create a symbolic link to the elements directory in webroot and load them that way too. But it probably is not a very good idea.

Comment: He shouldn't be pulling PHP code into the client side, like ever. Your solution will give him the parsed PHP (the outputted HTML) which is what he should do, not get actual PHP source. So symlinking PHP source into `webroot` would be a *bad* idea.

Answer (score 1):

The code above doesn't work:

```
.load(/controller/ajax_action/);
```

should be:

```
.load('/controller/ajax_action/');
```

...and

```
public function ajax_action() {
$this->renderElement('/elements/element_name.ctp');}
```

should be...

```
public function ajax_action() {
$this->render('/elements/element_name');}
```